# How to access and modify style of appending element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, appendchild

After drop, I am appending the child to the container.

My requirement is that I want to append the child at the cursor position. In order to do that, I need to access the style of child which I am appending.

I am doing that as `data.style={{...}}`. But it is saying as

> Cannot set property 'style' of undefined

```
 drop(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var data= event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
      //data.style={position:"relative"}

      event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      console.log(event.clientX)
      data.target.style={
        left : event.clientX + 'px',
        top : event.clientY+ 'px'
      }
```

Comment: Please, format your code to complete your question. You can find info and tips about it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: why are you mixing javascript selectors with reactjs, you can make use of ref here. can you post you full component code

Comment: formatting improvment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *style of **undefined***

Because the selector is undefined and it should be because if `data` is a node then it won't have `target` property. So, instead you have to do it directly on `data`:

```
data.style={
    left : event.clientX + 'px',
    top : event.clientY+ 'px'
}
```

Or you might want to change your code as:

```js
drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = document.getElementById(event.dataTransfer.getData("Text"));
  //data.style={position:"relative"}
  event.target.appendChild(data);
  console.log(event.clientX)
  data.style = {    // <------------apply styles on "data" node
    left: event.clientX + 'px',
    top: event.clientY + 'px'
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I could access the style of child.Thank you

Comment: But positioning the child at cursor position is not happening.Can you please help me in that @Jai

Comment: In that case you have to calculate the width, height of the target element and place it with subtraction of values.